# how to grep multiple words from different lines in same log

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I want to grep for files containing the words in different line from same log. the words are **checkCredit?msisdn=766117506** and **creditLimit**

The log file is like this

freeMemory 103709392time Mon Mar 12 04:02:13 IST 2018
http://127.0.0.1:8087/DialogProxy/services/ServiceProxy/**checkCredit?msisdn=767807544**&transid=45390124
freeMemory 73117016time Mon Mar 12 04:02:14 IST 2018
statusCode200
{statusCode=200, response=outstandingAmount 0.0 **creditLimit 0.0**, errorResponse=, responseTime=0}
this is balnce 0.0

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain a little bit more the structure of your input? Is it a log file containing only one line?

In addition, there is a typo _this is **balnce**_: have you copy-pasted it?

Comment: No its not one line, its different line in same log file. in my question i have uploaded the log file details and i want to filter only the checkCredit?msisdn=767807544 and creditLimit.

Comment: Like Gautam suggested, call grep and search for creditLimit. For instance, `grep creditLimit log.txt`. That works. If you need to combine the search, e.g. searching both words at the same time/line, that is unclear.

Comment: i need to grep both words same time using one grep command.

Comment: following the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle, you could do: `grep creditLimit log.txt | grep checkCredit` or whatever string. This will pipe your command and remove all lines that only match checkCredit.

With regards to the best way to do it, imho what works and is simple and readable is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
grep 'checkCredit?msisdn\|creditLimit' inputfile
```

Comment: grep 'checkCredit?msisdn=766117506\|creditLimit' inputfile catalina.out_bckp , when i run this command it also display only the creditLimit details why it doesn't show the  checkCredit?msisdn=766117506 details.

Comment: What is your `grep` version? GNU grep and BSD grep will behave differently. Please try: `grep 'checkCredit\|creditLimit' inputfile`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$ grep -e 'checkCredit?msisdn=766117506' -e 'creditLimit' <filename>
```

Comment: thank you for kind response. i have use this command then it only show the creditLimit details. why is that.?

Comment: since you are calling `egrep`, the string is assumed to be a regular expression. The `?` character is a regex operator. My best bet is this: the regex is interpreted and resolved.
In addition, that command would match every line containing one or more of those strings, not the requested lines with only the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try

`grep creditLimit log.txt | grep checkCredit`

Comment: No, he does not. Please check comments under OP question, specifically: _i need to grep both words same time using one grep command._

Answer (score 0):

> grep 'checkCredit?msisdn=766117506\|creditLimit' inputfile catalina.out_bckp , when i run this command it also display only the creditLimit details why it doesn't show the checkCredit?msisdn=766117506 details.

The log file as shown in your question post does not contain the `766117506`, so it's no wonder that grep doesn't find it. If you really have data with `766117506`, add them to the question.

> I have used this command **grep 'checkCredit?msisdn\|this is balnce' catalina.out_bckp |awk '$4 < 10 {print ;}'** it gave me good result but there is some missing values.

You haven't used `creditLimit` in that pattern, so it's no wonder that those lines are missing.

Comment: In my question its a example that i want to show you. this is balnce is another thing that i want grep from that log and this log contain different type of numbers as a example this only one number that appear in the log 766117506 there are so many numbers.

Comment: @mahesh - An example which doesn't exhibit the problem is useless; you'd have to show an example which allows to reproduce the problem. Also you'd have to state more precisely what _is some missing values_.

Comment: i have mentioned most important parts in the question regarding to what i actually want.